# Sybase error when creating several triggers

Tags: triggers, sybase

I have a weird error in sybase, basically I'm adding a functionality that includes creating several tables and triggers, in order to do this I'm creating a script that verifies if table or trigger exist and drops it to generate it again in case any of them needs and update, with the tables I'm having no issues but is not working with triggers:

Here is the syntaxs:

```
IF EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name="fu_codigos_alertas_UPD")
    DROP TRIGGER fu_codigos_alertas_UPD
GO

CREATE TRIGGER fu_codigos_alertas_UPD ON fu_codigos_alertas FOR UPDATE AS 
DECLARE 
   @seq      int 
BEGIN 
   /* Code */ 
END

CREATE TRIGGER fu_codigos_alertas_DEL ON fu_codigos_alertas FOR DELETE AS 
DECLARE 
   @seq      int 
BEGIN 
   /* Code */ 
END
```

If I execute one or the other alone they work, but if I execute them together it fails and i get:

**"DROP TRIGGER command not allowed within a trigger"**

Basically the error is when i execute 2 trigger drops, dunno why.

Anyone experimented a similar issue?

Comment: GO's after each END?

Comment: assuming this is Sybase ASE, DDL commands like `create proc/trigger` need to be submitted in their own batch; as access_granted has mentioned, separate your `create trigger` commands with `go`; I'm assuming you've left out the `drop trigger` test/command for the *_DEL trigger; if you happen to be running ASE 16.0+, take a look at the `create or replace trigger` command ... eliminates need for test/drop of trigger, and eliminates a need to re-issue any auditing settings (if being used) against the trigger

Comment: access_granted the GO worked

Comment: The missing 'go' was the primary issue. However, the reason for reporting a 'drop trigger' is that 'create trigger' implies a drop: no 'drop trigger' was explicitly specified there.